# Ubuntu 14.04 Mouse Touchpad gone bad

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, i3

I have a problem with my touchpad, but I don't think it's a hardware issue. I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and after a few days of use, the mouse pointer is behaving kind of wierd.

What it does is the following [some are mutually exclusive events]:

1. It just freezes.
2. I can move it around but the Left/Right Click functionality seems to be lost.
3. When I click on the Chromium browser tab it choose to "Close it" instead of going to it
4. To temporary troubleshoot I just put the System in suspend mode for few seconds, then it works like normal for half an hour or so, and the same issues arises.

What can be the cause? What can I do to fix this?

xinput result When it works fine...

zerobyte@Machine:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]

:~$ xinput list-props 14

Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (128):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (130): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (249): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (250):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (251):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (252):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (273):  1754, 5230, 1639, 4483
    Synaptics Finger (274): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (275):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (276):   229
    Synaptics Tap Durations (277):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (278):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (279):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (280):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (281):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (282): 104, 104
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (283): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (284):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (285): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.038314, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (286):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (287):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (288):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (289): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (290):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (291): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (292):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (293): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (294):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (295): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (296):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (297): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (298):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (299): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (300):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (301):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (302):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (303):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (304): 66, 42
    Synaptics Area (305):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (306): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (245):    2, 7
    Device Node (246):  "/dev/input/event5"

:~$ xinput list-props 13

Device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse':
    Device Enabled (128):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (130): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (249): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (250):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (251):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (252):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (245):    2, 1
    Device Node (246):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (253): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (255):  0
    Axis Labels (256):  "Rel X" (138), "Rel Y" (139)
    Button Labels (257):    "Button Left" (131), "Button Middle" (132), "Button Right" (133), "Button Wheel Up" (134), "Button Wheel Down" (135)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (258): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (259):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (260):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (261): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (262): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (263):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (264):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (265):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (266):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (267):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (268):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (269): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (270):  0

When it doesn't work fine...

:~$ xinput list-props 14

Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (128):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (130): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (249): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (250):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (251):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (252):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (273):  1754, 5230, 1639, 4483
    Synaptics Finger (274): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (275):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (276):   229
    Synaptics Tap Durations (277):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (278):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (279):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (280):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (281):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (282): 104, 104
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (283): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (284):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (285): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.038314, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (286):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (287):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (288):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (289): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (290):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (291): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (292):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (293): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (294):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (295): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (296):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (297): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (298):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (299): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (300):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (301):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (302):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (303):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (304): 66, 42
    Synaptics Area (305):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (306): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (245):    2, 7
    Device Node (246):  "/dev/input/event5"

:~$ xinput list-props 13

Device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse':
    Device Enabled (128):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (130): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (249): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (250):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (251):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (252):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (245):    2, 1
    Device Node (246):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (253): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (255):  0
    Axis Labels (256):  "Rel X" (138), "Rel Y" (139)
    Button Labels (257):    "Button Left" (131), "Button Middle" (132), "Button Right" (133), "Button Wheel Up" (134), "Button Wheel Down" (135)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (258): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (259):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (260):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (261): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (262): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (263):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (264):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (265):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (266):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (267):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (268):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (269): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (270):  0

Comment: Could you please add the outputs of `xinput list-props ID` of when the touchpad works and when it does not? `ID` is the id of your device, you can get a list of all input devices by running `xinput list`. Besides that, what is the reason you do not believe it to be a hardware problem? For example, does it work with other WMs/DEs?